# Reporting Services Mapping by Postcodes

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Is it possible to have maps cordinates plotting either by the use of Postcodes or Northings an Eastings co-ordinates. Can the map be acquired for Free from somewhere? As it seems only the USA map comes with SSRS by default but nothing available for UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download ESRI shapefiles for Great Britain free from the [Ordnance Survey](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html) and for Northern Ireland from [OpenDataNI](https://www.opendatani.gov.uk/dataset/lps-arcgis).  For your needs I would recommend the Boundary-Line option to get the various UK Administrative areas.  These come with names etc and are fantastic.

For postcodes, I don't think SSRS can just map them as is.  You will need to either invest in the Post Office's [Postcode Address File](http://www.royalmail.com/business/services/marketing/data-optimisation/paf) which costs regular licence money but is updated every 6 months, or you can rely on free resources (that include Northern Ireland) from websites like [Doogal](https://www.doogal.co.uk/PostcodeDownloads.php) who have a very comprehensive collection of the UK's postcodes, their geo data (Lat/long, Eas/Nor, etc) and additional meta data such as which ward they reside in.

From those two resources you can very easily build up a postcode lookup table that will hold your lat and long in a `spatial` data field to be returned by your queries.  This is the easiest way to feed SSRS mapping info and it 'just works' when you use the correct `geography` data type.

To add in a `spatial` column for your postcode table:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Postcodes]
ADD [SpatialPoint] GEOGRAPHY
GO

-- This query may take a loooooong time depending on your set up,
-- though you only have to run once across the whole dataset.
-- Obviously you will need to run again for any new postcodes.
UPDATE [dbo].[Postcodes]
SET [SpatialPoint] = geography::STPointFromText('POINT('
                                + CAST([Longitude] AS VARCHAR(20))
                                + ' '
                                + CAST([Latitude] AS VARCHAR(20))
                                + ')'
                                , 4326)
GO
```

Once you get cracking on the `spatial` querying, you will soon find that whilst the query will definitely take a very long time (my initial run on our crappy box took about 20 hours, though again only the once), you can use various `spatial` functions to determine which postcodes reside in which Boundary polygons and start to segment your data via all the postcodes that are a part of particular boundaries.  This is so very helpful when you can't be sure that your address data contains the County/Ward/Local Authority/etc.

You will also really want to look at upgrading your SQL Server version to at least 2012, as the spatial capabilities improve leaps and bounds in each version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are public sector (e.g. NHS) you can download Ordnance Survey's dataset "Codepoint with Polygons" which contains all the UK postcodes in separate files for each postcode area. For public sector, this is free. You need to get a PSMA licence as we did (Poole hospital).